# Page won't recognize global variable unless inside function in which it was reassigned

Tags: jquery

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7tZT.png)

Here is an image of the code that I'm using. I apologize for some unused code in here, but i've highlighted the parts that I find important.

At the top, I'm globally declaring "alert_ok_function". This, inside of my customAlert function, I am reasigning the variable to a function that's gotten from the "alert_function" parameter. I can then call the function using that variable name within the function, but not outside of it. At the bottom you can see that I'm trying to call it using a button that exists at the top frame, but it's returning an error saying that this variable is not a function. I'm under the impression that this should have been assigned globally, but that doesn't appear to be the case. What am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is strongly suggested that you take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour You will then want to edit your post and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It is a bad practice to simply post a picture of your code instead of creating a Snippet or Fiddle of the code.

Comment: Looking at your image, I can see where `alert_ok_function` is defined in your script and even used in your function, yet I do not see what is passed in as a parameter. Do you see any errors in Console?

Comment: @Twisty
The paramater is coming in from another page. The page in the image is an include on the page that this function is pulling from. The function passes correctly, and I know that because I can run it while I'm still inside the function. The problem comes when I exit the function and try to run it using a button click. Inside the function console.log(typeof alert_ok_function) will return as "function", but outside it will return as "undefined" even though it should be a global variable.

Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: You may want to recast the variable as a `const` instead of `var`. Without a Reproducible example, no one will be able to know how to help.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with frames. A "global" variable defined within one frame *is* globally accessible, but within that frame only. But it will not be visible in another frame. So, if you want to access `access_ok_function` from another frame (like `window.top`) you will have to address it with something like: `window.framename.access_ok_function` where `framename` needs to be the name of the actual frame in which the variable `access_ok_function` was defined.